# Rollercoaster simulation in matlab/javascript

Tags: javascript, matlab, simulation, physics

I'm having problem with a project that I'm working on in matlab which i'm then going to implement using javascript. The purpose is to use matlab to get a better understanding of the physics before moving over to javascript. The goal is to create some sort of a Rollercoaster simulation in matlab using differential equations and euler aproximation. Then to animate a block(cart) following the path.

The problem is that I can't get the approximation working on a arbitary path (equation), and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

So this is what i'm trying to do:

```
for t=1:h:tf
%acceleration

    ax(i) = (g*cos((-pi/4)))*sin(-pi/4)-((C*ro*A*vx(i)^2*sign(vx(i)))/(2*m))*sin(-pi/4);
    ay(i) = (g*cos((-pi/4)))*cos(-pi/4)+((C*ro*A*vy(i)^2*sign(vy(i)))/(2*m))*cos(-pi/4);

%speed
    vx(i+1) = vx(i)+h*ax(i);
    vy(i+1) = vy(i)+h*ay(i);

%position
    x(i+1) = x(i)+h*vx(i);
    y(i+1) = y(i)+h*vy(i);

    i = i+1; 
    speed = sqrt(vx(i)^2+vy(i)^2);
    plot(x(i),y(i),'or')
    pause(1/speed)

end
```

Where i'm following Newtons second law (F=ma => a = F/m) the only negative force component i'm using now is air resistance.

This is when i'm using a hardcoded path -> y=1-x, and it's working just fine!
But when i try to use an arbitary path, eg. 1/x, the angle is changed all the time, and i've tried things like putting each angle into an angle vector:

```
%% initial values 
vx(1) = 0;
vy(1) = 0;
x(1) = 0;
y(1) = 6.7056;
%Track Geometry Constants
h_start = 6.7056;        
l_end = 32;              
b = .055;                
w = .7;                  
p = .3;     
%% Creating path
path_x = linspace(0, 23, 1000);
path_y = (exp(-b*path_x).*(cos(w*path_x - p)) + 2.2*(exp(-(b)*path_x)));
path_y = path_y*(h_start/max(path_y));
path_x = path_x*(l_end/max(path_x));
%%

alpha = zeros(size(path_y));
for k=1:1:size(path_y)-1
    alpha(j) = atan(path_y(k+1)-path_y(k))/(path_x(k+1)-path_x(k));
    j= j+1;
end
```

But this doesn't appear to work.

**How can I make this work for an arbitrary path?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you look at the acceleration and velocity profiles (i.e. value vs. time) that are computed in the more complex case - do they make sense? Please define what is "_can't get the approximation working", "it's working just fine", "this doesn't appear to work". How do you judge what is working and what is not? Please try to formulate a **clear problem statement**.

Comment: By plotting the x and y position in after the approximation, the values goes to infinity when using the alpha vector of the angles. When using a straight line, the plot of the x and y values are following the line. Therefore I know that those calculation work.

Comment: If you can post the initial conditions, then we can run it, allowing us to have a better view on what goes wrong.

Comment: I'll put them in the post instead of here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty simple error in your loop. Two errors, actually.

1. You are indexing `alpha` with a variable, `j`, that doesn't exist and increment it in the loop, instead of just using `k`, which increments automatically in the loop.
2. The reason this isn't giving an error is that your loop never runs.   Because the size of `path_y` is not a single number, (the size is 1 x 1000), `k=1:1:size(path_y)-1` tries to create a loop that goes from 1 to 0 in steps of positive 1. Since this isn't possible, the loop is skipped. One option is to use `length`, not `size` here.

But the most important error: you didn't check your code line by line when it stopped working to confirm that every part of your code was doing what you thought it was when you wrote it. If you'd checked what `k=1:1:size(path_y)-1` was outputting, you should have been able to identify this problem very quickly.

Incidentally I think you can avoid the loop entirely (append a zero at the end if you really need this to have the same size as the path variables):
`alpha = atan(diff(path_y)./diff(path_x));`